# Get JIRA Sprint ID from Jira Issue

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to get Jira issue Sprint ID using JIRA-CIENT in node js. Sprint ID is not coming in Issue Attributes .
Any one have any idea how to get Sprint ID from Jira Issue using Jira Client module in nodejs

I have tried Jira Client in node js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must be having issueID with you.

Using below GET request you can access the Sprint Details of the mentioned issueID:

[http://host:port/rest/agile/1.0/issue/{issueID}](http://host:port/rest/agile/1.0/issue/%7BissueID%7D) OR [https://host:port/rest/agile/1.0/issue/{issueID}](https://host:port/rest/agile/1.0/issue/%7BissueID%7D)

Response Will be as below:

[image]